# RoboCopy not included in latest MSBuild Community release?

Tags: msbuild, build, build-automation

I'm setting up a RoboCopy job using the [MSBuild Community tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/). It seems however that the task has not been released, despite it being in the list of tasks on the project front page. The latest release v1.2.0.306 does not include it, but if it is present in the SVN trunk. Am I looking in the wrong place?

I know there is an MSBuild Extension project that also have a RoboCopy task, but I'm already using some of the other Community tasks, and I'd rather not make my build depend on two almost identical extension packs.

The Tigris site seems abandoned in terms of documentation, so I'm attempting to see if anyone in here knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you didn't notice it: the latest official release on the [download page](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList) (v1.2.0.306, exactly what you downloaded) is nearly five years old (February 2007).

Since then, obviously a lot of stuff happened in the trunk.
You can download and compile the trunk yourself, or you can use the nightly build which you can download at the bottom of the [main project page](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/):

> **Download The Latest Nightly Build**
>
> The latest test binaries and source from the automated build server.
>
> Version: 1.3.0.516 Date: 9/8/2011
>
> - [MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Nightly.zip](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Nightly.zip)
> - [MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Nightly.msi](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Nightly.msi)

I'm using this version.
So...yes, you are looking in the wrong place :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just seems odd to have a "latest" release that is nowhere near what people are actually using. Not cool having to explain the rest of the devs that they need to download and compile the trunk to get the build working. But I guess its hard to complain when it's free :o)

Comment: You don't **have** to compile the trunk yourself. Just use the nightly build. I just listed the possibility of compiling the trunk yourself as...well, as an additional option :-)

Answer (score 0):

MSBuild (latest) is also available through NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/MSBuildTasks

You can install it via GUI or in Package Manager Console run

```
Install-Package MSBuildTasks
```